# Testing a node app in chrome with cypress.io

Tags: node.js, testing, cypress

I am trying to test a clone of [this](https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js) node app with cypress. I only have very basic experience with cypress.

Unfortunately, the test of the node app (either started via webpack or via node --inspect) does not work. I have the fo

```
describe("Most basic test of adding a comments 2", function () {
  it("Adding one comment 2", function () {
    cy.pause();
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080");
    cy.pause();
    cy.get(".comment").click();
    cy.pause();
    cy.get("div#viewer.pdfViewer").click(50, 300);

    cy.get("input#pdf-annotate-point-input").type("Testkommentar{enter}");
    cy.get("input#pdf-annotate-point-input").debug();
    expect(localStorage.getItem("example.pdf/pen/color")).to.be.not.null;
    expect(localStorage.getItem("exaxmple.pdf/annotations")).to.be.not.null;
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems that cypress has no control over the Chrome browser. The browser is started and the URL is called but there is no further action and spcifically the pause() commands are not working.

Does anybody know whether I have to set some specific settings due to the fact that this is a node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test case your 'expect' code will be executed earlier unless you add it after cypress command or you can use promise function like this,

```
describe("Most basic test of adding a comments 2", function () {
    it("Adding one comment 2", function () {
      cy.pause();
      cy.visit("http://localhost:8080");
      cy.pause();
      cy.get(".comment").click();
      cy.pause();
      cy.get("div#viewer.pdfViewer").click(50, 300);

      cy.get("input#pdf-annotate-point-input").type("Testkommentar{enter}");
      cy.get("input#pdf-annotate-point-input").debug();
      //add following code after cypress command
      cy.wait(500).then(()=>{
        expect(localStorage.getItem("example.pdf/pen/color")).to.be.not.null;
        expect(localStorage.getItem("exaxmple.pdf/annotations")).to.be.not.null; 
      })
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! As you can guess I am not native in JS :-) I am struggling with the concept of async execution in this case, specifically for the wait statement in the beginning. Is a series of then statements the pattern to use when I want to achieve a strict stepwise execution of test steps?

Comment: If you use strictly with cypress commands like 'visit', 'get' they are already stepwise. If you want something your own not limited to cypress command then you would need promise function to make sure it executed after. Read more from the official doc here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous

Comment: Thanks! I finally ended up using https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise as this makes the code more readable.